# Retrieveing ALL head elements in document including iframe

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add `style` elements to all ALL the `head` elements in a document, including those in an iframe.

if i use

```
var heads = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
```

It just returns the first head element and not the ones in the iframe.
this is the complete code :

```
var heads = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.type = "text/css";
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
for(var i=0;i<heads.length;i++) heads[i].appendChild(style);
```

but this doesn't seem to work!
am i doing something wrong here...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what worked for me. thanx for all the help btw -_-

```
try { if(top.location.href != window.location.href) { return; } }
catch(e) { return; }

window.setTimeout(getAllHeads, 1000);

function getAllHeads() {
    var heads = new Array();
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    if(head) addHead(head);
    var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    for(var i = 0, len = frames.length; i < len; i++) {
        var frame = frames[i];
        head = (frame.contentDocument).getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        if(head) addHead(head);
    }

    function addHead(h) { heads.push(h); }

    alert(heads.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you `getElementsbyTagName('iframe')` and then get the children elements?

Beware that you may be hitting up against security restrictions on iframes that are put there to prevent cross site scripting.

Comment: but that would just give me iframe heads element, where as i want to get ALL the head elements, not just the ones in the iframes.